# Polymorphic relationships via a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to build relationships between models based on a screenshot?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhjMb.png)

Upd: I would like to receive payment items via $payment->items().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-table-structure

Since your table names and column names do not follow the conventions set by Laravel, a few extra parameters are needed.

```php
class Good extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'good';

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Payment::class, 'entity', 'item_payments');
    }
}
```

```php
class Service extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'service';

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Payment::class, 'entity', 'item_payments');
    }
}
```

```php
class Payment extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Service::class, 'entity', 'item_payments');
    }

    public function goods()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Good::class, 'entity', 'item_payments');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to receive payment items via $payment->items()

Comment: Then change the method name